# Low end is missing from audio through sound interface and condenser mic going to macOS

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces, voice, equalization

My setup is very cheap. I consider myself a beginner, so I wanted to learn and let this learning journey progressively unveil the need for better gear.

1. Mic: [Neewer® NW-700 Professional Studio Broadcasting Recording Condenser Microphone](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00XOXRTX6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
2. Cable mic to audio interface: [No Bull Music Gear' Premium XLR Cable (Black, 3m)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00LOQ97GM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
3. Audio interface: [Behringer UMC22 Computer Audio Interface](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00FFIGZF6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
4. Operating system: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 (19H1323)

By this default setup, I get a very metallic sound for my voice, with almost no low end.

**Question 1**: Is this expected? Why? is it because the audio interface does not enjoy of any processing from sound drivers, whereas using a mini plug cable into the audio jack does?

**Question 2**: How can I fix this? Do I need a physical mixing board to provide better equalisation into the audio interface, or can I use a DAW to devote an auxiliar track to receive input from audio interface, apply better equalisation to it, and outputting to a custom MIDI interface that I can then use for both Zoom and OBS?

Comment: That setup is basic, but should be functional. Do you have the phantom power on - switch on the back of the Behringer? [Power on before connecting the mic & mute inputs throughout the process].

Comment: I do have it on :)

Comment: There's nothing in your setup to explain what might be wrong, then. Short of swapping things out one at a time to eliminate the source, there's little else I can suggest.